# UrlClassLoader can not load the class in the jar

Tags: classnotfoundexception, urlclassloader

I use URLClassLoader to load the class，and I am sure that the class is int the jar，
but this exception has occurred：

[exception:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYGo2.png)

and the code is here:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { jarURL }, classLoader);
Class.forName("com.demo.bitmap.udf.BitmapAndUDF", true, urlClassLoader);
```

and the classes in jar is：
[classes in jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1DoB.png)

I want to know why ？